# DSP library for Software Defined Radio

Tags: interpolation, software-defined-radio, decimation, software-implementation

Can anyone recommend a good C library for SDR? To be more specific I just need a function in C to compute coefficients for CIC compensation filter (I need to do it in real time, so Matlab is not an option)

Thanks.

Comment: I believe (but I'm not certain) that `liquid dsp` does what you need.